# Google Maps - JSON Object markers from VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, json, google-maps-api-3

I have used VB to create a JSON object of markers.

```
    Dim nearbyLocations = CType(sqldata.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty),
                                DataView)

    For Each location As DataRowView In nearbyLocations
        markers.Add(
             String.Format(
                 "{{ title: ""AccName:{0}"", position: new google.maps.LatLng({1}, {2})}}", 
                     location("accgrpname"), 
                     location("Lat"), 
                     location("Long")))            
    Next

    Dim locationsJson = "[" & String.Join(",", markers.ToArray()) & "]"
```

How would i reference this object in javascript to plot on a map?

Final JSON is the following:

```
    [{ title: "AccName: Name", position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.0000, -0.1000)}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add an example of the resulting Json to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use AJAX call to load the JSON object created using VB code. You may use JQuery to make ease of your ajax call and the data you received will be converted to JavaScript object for you.

a quick sample looks like (un-tested code):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: service,  //your VB service
        dataType: 'json',  //could be JSONP 
        success: function(data){ var mk = new google.maps.Marker(data); }
    });
```

Comment: I guess it is too late for the answer now. Did not realize the question was aked two years ago ~_~